# SharedPreferences and different languages

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Hi I have a problem with PreferencesFragment and storing the settings. When I change the phone's language in Android stored values of my preferences are still in the previous language and aren't set in the PreferencesFragment. I have different values folders for each language. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please explain the question more clearly. The preference strings aren't changing (eg. title, summary etc.)? Or you want to automatically change the stored values of the preferences?

Comment: I want to automatically change the stored values of the preferences

Comment: Finish and restart your PreferenceActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you want to change the values of the preferences. I don't think it can be done automatically by the API. You will have to write your own code to set the preference values.

You can store the language dependent preference values in `values-xx` directories. For eg. strings, integers etc.

When someone changes the phone's language your Activity will restarted. You should use this as an opportunity to change the preference values in `onCreate`. First, store the current language being used, so that it can be used to detect whether the language was changed. You can use the `Locale` to do it (`Locale.getDefalt()`)

Now, if you detect a language change, just get the values by using the `Resources` object by calling `getResources()` and change all the language dependent preference values.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it for ListPreference and MultiSelectListPreference

Comment: Why are you storing language dependent strings in preferences? You should use strings for displaying and store as integers. That's why there are two attributes for LisPreference (entries, entryValues) . From the integer value which is stored, you can get the mapped translated string.

Answer (score 0):

The Preference language in your application is not dependent on your phone language. If its dependent, you don't even need it in your application , first place. You should make coding in such a way that you have **Auto** language which depends on phone language.